# Rails 3 is it safe to name a model "Request" 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm on Rails 3.0.9 and I'm wondering if it is safe to name a model `Request`, I know there are some reserved words / special classes in Ruby, Rails and SQL, wondering this is one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm quite certain it's not safe to use "Request". Here's an [old list](http://web.archive.org/web/20150504103211/http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rails_reserved_words) of reserved words in rails that includes "Request". I'm not even going to bother looking it up for the latest version of rails because I'm certain it's there as well. But even if it's not you should still  avoid using it since it's such an overloaded word in web development.

**Edit:**

Ok I lied, I did look it up :) There's a module named `Request` in rails 3. Here's a short clip of code

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Http
    module Cache
      module Request
```

Comment: @Johnny Klassy: If you want to use Request, try prefixing it. In Ye Olden Times, we used to name classes with some company specific prefix to distinguish our internally built classes versus those that came from some external framework (e.g. JkRequest => jk_request.rb). Food for thought...